# Pick image from gallery in fullscreen mode

Tags: android, android-intent, android-gallery

in my options menu I have a function that can change the applications background. To do this, I start an Activity where the user can pick an image from his gallery.

Now to the problem: I want the **gallery** to be displayed in **fullscreen-mode**.

My AndroidManifest.xml contains

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon"
             android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
             android:label="@string/app_name">
```

And I'm showing the gallery via

```
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
 i.setType("image/*");
 startActivityForResult(i, PICK_REQUEST);
```

Does anybody have an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether the gallery is displayed full-screen or not is dependent on the gallery app itself. As far as I know, that cannot be changed unless you supply your own gallery app and use a custom intent to call that

Comment: "Calling startActivity() or startActivityForResult() will open a new screen in whatever way it defines itself (if it uses a floating theme it will be floating, otherwise it will be full screen)." - Common Tasks and How to Do Them in Android